# VBA - Set range by matching column and row values

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA and after lots of searching I haven't been able to find any help to the following problem.

I have a fairly large and complex table containing a lot of data. The data within the table has been conditional formatted to have different color fills. Using the following code, I am able to count the number of cells of a certain color within each range.

However I am looking to replace the range with for example something along the lines of; IF column C value matches "Apples" AND IF row 3 value matches "Farm A" THEN count green fills within this area.

The code I am using so far is below.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lColorCounter As Long
Dim rngCell As Range

Sheets("Matrix").Select
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("F140:O150")
For Each rngCell In rng
   If Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(185, 255, 185) Then
        lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
    End If
Next
  Sheets("Summary").Activate
    Sheet3.Range("C4") = lColorCounter
     lColorCounter = 0
```

Hope this makes sense and any help will really be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, this has a dynamic row loop (check for value of **Apples**) and a dynamic column loop (check for **color** of cells).

The range of the 2nd loop is determined by the size of your merged cell ("Farm A") which starts in cell `C2`. So if you change your `Farm A` merged cell to span 20 columns, the loop will expand to those 20 columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Long, FarmA As Integer, MyCell As Range, lColorCounter As Long
Dim Matrix As Worksheet: Set Matrix = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Matrix")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Matrix
    FarmA = .Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Count + 2 'Determine size of merged cell "FarmA"
        For i = 3 To .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Loop through used rows in Col B
            If .Range("B" & i) = "Apples" Then 'If condition is met, move to next line, else, check next row
                For Each MyCell In .Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, FarmA)) 'set serach range
                    If MyCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(185, 255, 185) Then 'search for format
                        lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
                    End If
                Next MyCell
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox lColorCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However using your example, would I be able to set the range, as cells within a column titled "Apples" and a Row titled "Farm A". i.e to get rid of ("F140:O150") within the code completely?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned the range is dynamic due to import of new data and use of filter and sort on the table. Thanks

Comment: The table is on the matrix sheet, and i guess you can see I am really new to this. I've uploaded a picture which will hopefully help. It should match Apples to Farm A and be able to state that there 14 occurrences of a green fill for example. Hope that helps! [pic](https://ibb.co/j6LHry)

Comment: Is your table column length always the same? Farm A is always in columns C:I?

Comment: Unfortunately not, more columns and rows can be added. But Farm A will always be in Column C

Comment: I have just realised that the solution is not stopping at the "Farm A" column and continuing to count into "Farm B" and "Farm C" columns. It is counting the correct rows though. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the top left location of your merged cell that says farm A in cell C2?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I've added 9 for the number of merged cells. However, if I MsgBox FarmA it provides a value of 3935 instead of what I would imagine should be 12.

Comment: Add `MsgBox FarmA` right before starting the `i` loop and let me know what value it shows. This was working for me so im confused. The number should correspond with the column index where the merged cell ends. If your merged cell is from C to E it should show 5 since it ends on the 5th column

Comment: I'm getting 3935 just before the i loop. I have no idea why it is so large but I suppose I could subtract a figure to have it correspond to the correct column